# Should 'popular question' et al be based on votes rather than views?

Tags: discussion, badges, views, rankings

The point came up to day that badges such as 'popular question' that are view based should really be based on votes not on views.  The reasoning went something like this.

- Most of the traffic is now coming from Google and other search engines not SO's engine.
- These search engines aren't as good as we'd like to think so someone may hit 3 or 4 questions before they find the one their looking for.

That being the case, those 3 or 4 questions are getting recognized for something that they in fact should not be recognized for.  They are just getting hit by accident.

Thuoghts?

Answer (score 5):

The purpose for the Popular Question series of badges is to distinguish a question that is getting looked at a lot, regardless of whether it was exceptionally useful or not. There is already badges based on votes on your question: [Nice Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/20/nice-question), [Good Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/21/good-question), and [Great Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/22/great-question). Those are the badges that actually reward useful questions. The popular ones just say that people have seen your question.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think that it should be based on votes.  Sometimes I'll look at a question and think to myself "That's a pretty good question."  But that doesn't mean that I'm going to vote for it.  I may look at the number of votes it already has and decide that it already has enough, or even too many, votes.

Comment: Really?  You've never looked at a question (or an answer) and though, now that has just too many votes (when compared to other questions or answers with roughly equal value)?